# pivot_wider() on regex occurrence

Tags: r, regex, pivot

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
my.df <- data.frame(c("header_1", "header_2", "header_3", 
                      "product_1", "qty:3", "date:20151212", "qty:2", "date:20151215",
                      "product_2", "qty:11", "date:20151123",
                      "product_3", "qty:53", "date:20151005", "qty:33", "date:20161130", "qty:33", "date:20160607"))
names(my.df) <- "col1"
```

I saw a possible approach in this forum entry "[move every other row in a row to a new column](https://community.rstudio.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-move-every-other-row-in-a-column-into-a-new-column-in-r/61625)" but that would only work if I have continuous data in the column. Since in my case there are repeating sections `product_1`, `product_2` and `product_3`, I was thinking whether there is a possibility to 'restart' `pivot_wider()` on a regex occurrence, e.g. `^product.*` or similar ? Alternatively, I could try and subset each repeating section and `rbind()` them afterwards. Though this seems rather excessive since a file might have dozens of repeating product sections.

The desired output would look like this:

```
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+--------+---------------+
| header_1 | header_2 | header_3 | product_1 | qty:3  | date:20151212 |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+--------+---------------+
| header_1 | header_2 | header_3 | product_1 | qty:2  | date:20151215 |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+--------+---------------+
| header_1 | header_2 | header_3 | product_2 | qty:11 | date:20151123 |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+--------+---------------+
| header_1 | header_2 | header_3 | product_3 | qty:53 | date:20151005 |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+--------+---------------+
| header_1 | header_2 | header_3 | product_3 | qty:33 | date:20161130 |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+--------+---------------+
| header_1 | header_2 | header_3 | product_3 | qty:33 | date:20160607 |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+--------+---------------+
```

I am obviously not bound to this approach but this is where my current understanding of R and ideas brought.

Comment: Will there ever be more than one set of `header_*` values? That is, will your data ever have some products under, say `header_1`, `header_2`, `header_3` and another set of products under, say, `header_4`, `header_5` and `header_6`?

Comment: No, there will always be three header rows followed by the repeating product segments with varying amounts of qty and date occurrences in each segment. The header rows identify the file type, hold customer information and the global date when the file was created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another alternative with `tidyverse`. Use `separate` for your `qty` and `date` columns, and an additional `separate` for `product` which can have multiple entries. You could create an index `ind` for each row, where a new row is determined after a `date` field is reached.

This will set up your data so you can use `pivot_wider` to get the desired format. Finally, you can use `fill` to copy down your headers and product number for the empty `NA` values.

```
library(tidyverse)

my.df %>%
  separate(col1, into = c("key", "value"), sep = ":", fill = "right") %>%
  mutate(ind = cumsum(lag(key, default = "date") == "date")) %>%
  separate(key, into = c("key1", "key2"), sep = "(?<=product)_", remove = FALSE, fill = "right") %>%
  mutate(value = coalesce(value, key2, key)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ind, names_from = key1, values_from = value) %>%
  fill(c(starts_with("header"), "product"))
```

**Output**

```
    ind header_1 header_2 header_3 product qty   date    
  <int> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr> <chr>   
1     1 header_1 header_2 header_3 1       3     20151212
2     2 header_1 header_2 header_3 1       2     20151215
3     3 header_1 header_2 header_3 2       11    20151123
4     4 header_1 header_2 header_3 3       53    20151005
5     5 header_1 header_2 header_3 3       33    20161130
6     6 header_1 header_2 header_3 3       33    20160607
```

Comment: `separate` is... exactly what I needed right now to convince me to stop using `pipe()` on an embedded Perl script ☺. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
## find the product entries in my.df$col1
prods <- grep("product_\\d+", my.df$col1)
## add one entry that is the last row number + 1
prods <- c(prods, nrow(my.df)+1)
## initialize the result
res <- NULL
## loop over all of the rows where a new product starts
for(i in 1:(length(prods)-1)){
  ## for each new product, make a two-column matrix of qty and date
  mat <- matrix(my.df$col1[(prods[i]+1):(prods[(i+1)]-1)], 
                ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
  ## change the names of the matrix
  colnames(mat) <- c("qty", "date")
  ## make it into a dataset
  mat <- as_tibble(mat)
  mat <- mat %>% 
    ## add the product column
    add_column(product = my.df$col1[prods[i]]) %>% 
    ## put the variables in the right order
    select(product, qty, date)
  ## put together with res
  res <- bind_rows(res, mat)  
  
}
## add in header columns
res <- res %>% 
  add_column(h1 = my.df$col1[1], 
             h2 = my.df$col1[2], 
             h3 = my.df$col1[3]) %>% 
  select(h1, h2, h3, product, qty, date)
res
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#   h1       h2       h3       product   qty    date         
#   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>  <chr>        
# 1 header_1 header_2 header_3 product_1 qty:3  date:20151212
# 2 header_1 header_2 header_3 product_1 qty:2  date:20151215
# 3 header_1 header_2 header_3 product_2 qty:11 date:20151123
# 4 header_1 header_2 header_3 product_3 qty:53 date:20151005
# 5 header_1 header_2 header_3 product_3 qty:33 date:20161130
# 6 header_1 header_2 header_3 product_3 qty:33 date:20160607
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code here, which uses the `zoo::na.locf` function to carry over the last seen "product" value.
Then you can either repeat the same for "qty" and essentially only keep the "date"-rows, because they will at that point have all the data you need - or if you want to do more complex stuff with your "product"-blocks, you can also `split` the dataframe into a list and work through each chunk with `purrr::map_dfr`.
I didn't see why you were carrying over the "header_1", "header_2" and "header_3" columns, since they are adding no value and just repeat. I have dropped them for that reason...

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(zoo)
library(purrr)


# variant 1, do all with na.locf
df1 <- my.df %>%
  mutate(
    product = na.locf(str_extract(col1, "^product.+$"), na.rm = F),
    qty = na.locf(str_extract(col1, "(?<=^qty:).+$"), na.rm = F),
    date = str_extract(col1, "(?<=^date:).+$")
  ) %>%
  filter(
    !is.na(product),
    !is.na(qty),
    !is.na(date)
  ) %>%
  distinct(product, qty, date)


# variant 2, split the df into product chunks and prepare a result on that list
df_var2 <- my.df %>%
  mutate(
    product = na.locf(str_extract(col1, "^product.+$"), na.rm = F),
  ) %>%
  split(., .$product) %>%
  map_dfr(
    .f = ~ .x %>%
      mutate(
        qty = na.locf(str_extract(col1, "(?<=^qty:).+$"), na.rm = F),
        date = str_extract(col1, "(?<=^date:).+$")
      ) %>%
      na.omit() %>%
      distinct(qty, date),
    .id = "product"
  )
```

Comment: Thanks alex_jwb90, your approach works fine, too. As a clarification, the header rows contain the filename as well, thus I need to keep them. The script is part of a loop to go through ca. 10,000 of those files and parse the content. Having the filename allows me to cross-check the correctness later on.